# Querying for a local state variable doesn't immediately return a result

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm querying for my local variable `isLeftSidebarOpen` and I thought that it should immediately return result without `loading` state. `isLeftSidebarOpen` is initialized when `ApolloClient` is created.

```
const data = {
    isLeftSidebarOpen: false,
};
const initializeCache = cache => {
    cache.writeData({ data });
};
```

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
        credentials: 'include',
    }),
    cache,
    resolvers,
});

initializeCache(cache);
```

```
 query IsLeftSidebarOpen {
   isLeftSidebarOpen @client
 }
```

```
 const { data, loading } = useQuery(IS_LEFTSIDEBAR_OPEN);
 console.log(data);
 console.log(loading);
```

The result is:

```
undefined
true
{ isLeftSidebarOpen: false }
false
```

Whereas I expected to be:

```
{ isLeftSidebarOpen: false }
false
```

What is wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local resolver interface has to be asynchronous as apollo client can simply not know wether you'll implement your local resolvers asynchronoulsy or not. Asynchronous works in both scenarios, synchronous does not. Even if your implementation itself is synchronous, apollo will `await` that function before setting `loading` to false.

Another "benefit" is that your query behaves the exact same way, regardless of it being resolved locally or remote.

However, `cache.readQuery` is a synchronous operation, so you can use that instead of using a local resolver to return the data immediately, given that you get a cache hit.